# How do you show that repeatedly dividing $n$ by $2$ takes $\log_2n$ steps to reach $1$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I don't see why $n, n/2, n/4, n/8, \dots, 1$ takes $\log_2 n$ steps. Is there a more general statement on this repeated division?

Comment: Suppose for simplicity that $n=2^k$ for some $k$. How many divisions by 2 would it take to get down to 1?

Comment: I used my calculator and got a number with decimal places, not sure if it is right

Comment: Let's say $n=32 = 2^5$. Repeatedly divide by 2: (1) $32/2=16$, (2) $16/2 = 8$, (3) $8/2 = 4$, (4) $4/2=2$, (5) $2/2 = 1$ and stop. Total divisions = 5. You do understand that "log2n" should be interpreted as "log to the base 2 of $n$, right?

Comment: @MathNewb The two buttons on your calculator are labelled $\log$ and $\ln$. The first takes logs to base 10 and the second takes natural logarithms (base $e\approx 2.718$). To calculate base-2 logs ($\log_2$), you need to use the equation $\log_2 x = \frac{\log x}{\log 2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Prove by induction that after $k$ steps you are at $n/2^k$. If $n/2^k \leq 1$ then $k \geq \log_2 n$.

(Actually, this works only for $n$ which is a power of $2$. Otherwise you get something like $(1/2)\log_2 n$.)